# ping server vs. connecting to server

Tags: ip, tcp, ping, icmp

Networking newb here. Under what circumstances could you fail to ping a remote server with the ping command, but still be able to connect to it via other means (as long as it was still TCP/IP)?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: Your answer would help me a lot more, if there were an arrow button on this page that you managed to suddenly find sightly, lol. It's easy to forget that decent questions need decency too.

Comment: I didn't necessarily mean my answer, nor was I trolling for votes. If you do not accept (the check mark, not a vote) one of the answers, the question will keep popping to the top forever, looking for an answer.

Comment: yeah that's cool, moderators gotta moderate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many possible reasons, but the most likely is that there is a firewall or access list that is blocking ICMP.

Answer (score 4):

ICMP echo requests or replies could be blocked anywhere in the path, including at the endpoint itself. There are many circumstances or reasons this may be the case.

Answer (score 3):

As a [self-professed] newb, you will advance more quickly in your network understanding if you flip your thinking around. So instead, ask:

Why would you think "ping" (aka ICMP ECHO packets) would be in any way related to "connect to it" (aka open a TCP socket)?

Success of ICMP ECHO does tell you some facts (eg, IP works between the two points, the end thing responds to ICMP ECHO REQuests, and more.) But you wouldn't jump to the erroneous conclusion that ICMP ECHO success tells you anything explicitly about TCP success.

Comment: perhaps TCP ping would be a necessary but not sufficient condition. So if you cannot TCP ping, than you cannot etc etc...is that not correct?